# How do I add more particles?

Tags: particles

I have set to have 500 particles but blender only adds about 50. How do I add more? I know I can increase the number but why do I get like 10% of the amount I put in there? Why doesn't blender add 500 when I ask 500? How do I add say 2000 particles so it actually spawns 2000 in different places?

See the sample file:
https://www18.zippyshare.com/v/56ewtGPx/file.html

I am using a uvmapped texture to guide where I want particles. Texture should be included inside the blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have 500 and not 50 but 450 of them are masked out by your image textures.

[image]

Comment: So the images just work as masks and not as guides where the particles are placed? There is no way to get those 500 to spawn according to the image?

Comment: @Life Yes there are ways. One would be to subdivide the mesh a bit, weight paint the plane like your image which makes a vertex group of the painted area and then select that vertex group in particles->vertex groups->density

Comment: I don't want to use vertex groups painting because it is really cumbersome. Essentially I need certain kind of particle system on certain kind of texture on the map and vertex colors is really annoying for that because I have 4 or 5 different particle+texture combinations and I don't want to try to keep 3-5 different vertex colors in sync.

Comment: @Life I dont know. I guess you need to open a new question for that. You could up your count from 500 to 5000, but maybe there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no animation or want all particles to show at all times tick the options *Unborn* and *Died* in the *Properties Window > Partices > Render* panel

[image]

This will make it so that particles are visible at all times, before being emitted, and after dying or spending their life cycle.

Comment: On the example I still get just about 50 particles when I have 500 set.